# 2018 Honda Civic warning lights all on power steering,abs,emissions,uphill contaminated gas?

Tags: honda, fuel-system, civic

2018 Honda Civic ex with 2000 miles on it. Abs emissions power steering uphill lights all on the dash. Took it to the dealer and they said it is contaminated gas? Has anyone every had this happen? I honestly thought it was a computer glitch. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've not heard of "bad gas" causing the issues you describe, but stranger things ... Question for you: Did you change your gas purchase habits? Go to a different gas station? What did they suggest to fix the issue?

Comment: Same gas station that we have been using for years. They are going to flush the tank and refill. 500 thanks

Comment: I might believe that the emissions light could come on for 'contaminated gas" but abs & power steering.... seems like they came up with a story to smooth-talk a customer... But not many vehicles that I have come across will have a warning light to even detect water in fuel... That is the sort of thing I would have done for fun, after fitting a combined fuel filter separator unit...

Comment: I seem to remember something similar happening on a 2017 fit. Was never resolved iirc there were no stored codes in the ecm and the car was too new for out AM scantools to access the ebcm etc...